# Is Promise.All a way to run multiple methods in a parallel way even without resolve?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I am new to Promise that I know a basic Promise would take a method would treat a function like `(resolve, reject) => { ... }` and deal the result accordingly, and Promise.all seems can deal with an array of functions in a parallel manner. However, I also see some usage of function in a Promise that's not taken the `(resolve, reject)` as input but just do `new Promise(() => { return 1 + 1;})`, so if I have couple of function that doesn't need to `resolve`, e.g

```
function sum(a, b) { return a + b; }
function sub(a, b) { return a - b; }
function multiple(a, b) { return a * b; }
```

If I use Promise.all on three functions, does that mean I am running 3 of them in a parallel way? Something like

```
Promise.all([()=>sum(1,2), ()=>sub(1,2), ()=>multiple(1,2)])
```

Overall, is `Promise.all` a concept that we can run multiple javascript methods (whether async or not, resolve or not) in a parallel manner?

Comment: Please refactor your code for proper understanding.

Comment: `Promise.all` takes an array of *promises*, not functions. All it does is wait for all of them to resolve. It will not execute anything.

Comment: Also, there is no parallelism with `Promise.all`. *Most of the time*, the code you write in JavaScript is executed in a single thread. `Promise.all` doesn't change that.

Comment: Promise.all has nothing to do with regular functions. All, Promise.all does, is return a promise that resolves as soon as all the other promises are resolved

Answer (score 0):

No, Promise.all receives an iterator like an Array. so when you call promise.all it iterate over the element passed. if they are function nothing happens (dead function) if you executed them the returned value is checked and thus these functions run synchronously. now further how it evaluate the values is listed below.

```
var p = Promise.all([]); // will be immediately resolved
var p2 = Promise.all([1337, "hi"]); // non-promise values will be ignored, but the evaluation will be done asynchronously just once for promise.all
console.log(p);
console.log(p2)
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('the stack is now empty');
    console.log(p2);
});

// logs
// Promise { <state>: "fulfilled", <value>: Array[0] }
// Promise { <state>: "pending" }
// the stack is now empty
// Promise { <state>: "fulfilled", <value>: Array[2] }
```